# JSON API Structure to Coldfusion Output

Tags: json, coldfusion

I thought I knew what I was doing taking a JSON structure from an API call and outputting the values in ColdFusion, but I keep getting an error.  I first call the API with a GET using CFHTTP. I then take the returned JSON value and deserialize it as shown below.

```
<cfset myJsonStruct = deserializeJSON(#sch.filecontent#) /> 

<!--- <cfdump var="#myJsonStruct#">  --->
<cfdump var="#myJsonStruct.activities#">
```

When I dump the deserialized values I get the structure shown in the screen grab below.

[image: screen_grab]

I want to now loop through the data show in the green arrays, but it chokes at "2017-09-20". I'm guessing it does not like the structure name to have numbers or a date?

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this:  <cfdump var="#myJsonStruct['2017-21-09']#"/>

Comment: Or this: `<cfdump var="#structFind(myJsonStruct,'2017-09-20')#"/>`

Comment: How do you loop?

Comment: The first idea (Randy's) idea did not work.  It returns the following error: Element 2017-09-20 is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

Comment: The second idea (Miguel's) idea did not work either. It produces the following error: "Cannot find 2017-09-25 key in structure."

Comment: Both of those methods should work. Look at your data carefully. Your code example and dump capture show the format as `2017-09-20` (yyyy-mm-dd) but the error capture that you provided shows the format as `2017-21-09` (yyyy-dd-mm).

Comment: It looks to me that '2017-09-20' is not an element of `myJsonStruct`. Rather it's an element of `myJsonStruct.days`. What happens if you do: `<cfdump var="#myJsonStruct.days['2017-21-09']#"/>`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<cfdump var="#myJsonStruct['2017-09-20']#">
```

but after analysing your dump you probably need to use:

```
<cfdump var="#myJsonStruct.days['2017-09-20']#">
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with nested structs, it is important to remember that you can't skip past a struct. You have to specifically indicate a key in each struct down to the key you want to access. In order to access the array in the "assignments" key indicate each key in the path: days['2017-09-20']['assignments'].

You should be able to  to dump the array. By using bracket notation, you can reference dynamic struct key names and key names that are not simple alphanumeric values.

To access the "shifts" array, make sure you indicate the array index of assignments: days['2017-09-20']['assignments'][1]['shifts'] for example.